# Setting unique ID to a table cell created in JavaScript from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I create table cells and rows in JavaScript and add information from JSON file in table cells. I assign a unique id to table cells in my code but I get error that the ids are undefined and when I want to use them later on the ids are "blank".

I can't understand why this happens! Note that the table gets created and everything shows as i will. Below you can see my code and other relevant information, please no jQuery, thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="info">
    <table id="country">
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
            document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.api.countries.length; i = i + 2) {
                document.getElementById("country").innerHTML += "<tr><td id = '" + jsonData.api.countries[i].code + "' > " + "<img src=" + jsonData.api.countries[i].flag + ">" + "<p>" + jsonData.api.countries[i].country + "</p>" + "</td>" +
                    "<td id = '" + jsonData.api.countries[i + 1].code + "' > " + "<img src=" + jsonData.api.countries[i + 1].flag + ">" + "<p>" + jsonData.api.countries[i + 1].country + "</p>" + "</td>"
                    +"</tr>";


                }
```

The error that i get in console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined
at XMLHttpRequest.myfunction
```

Here is a picture of how the html looks like in page elements:

[image]

Sample of jsonfile:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do i = i + 2 in your for loop ?

Comment: @JSLover i do that because i want the loop to continue get information from where the row was ended. for example first it takes the index 0, then 1 and now the row ends. next time its starts from i=0+2 and continues

Comment: @Blink22 can you add a sample of the json file?

Comment: @stanchacon it is now updated

Comment: @Blink22 Can you add the object instead of an image?

Comment: @stanchacon i use xmlhttpreq to get the object from an api with unique auth key from rapidapi.com. so its not a file that i downloaded from somewhere and use. sorry for missleading in question!

Comment: @Blink22 I know but you can just copy a sample of the output and paste it here

Comment: {api: {…}}
api:
results: 129
countries: Array(129)
[0 … 99]
0:
country: "Albania"
code: "AL"
flag: "https://media.api-football.com/flags/al.svg"
__proto__: Object
1:
country: "Algeria"
code: "DZ"
flag: "https://media.api-football.com/flags/dz.svg" 2:
country: "Andorra"
code: "AD"
flag: "https://media.api-football.com/flags/ad.svg"

Comment: @Blink22 check if this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfysnu/8/) is useful to you

Comment: @stanchacon hey this works! can you add eventhandler for each cell in for your code as well? because when someone chooses a country i want to display some other info! thanks alot! i would accept your comment as answer, but you should post it as answer first so that i could do it!

Comment: @Blink22 sure I will add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is an example using vanilla js and some custom json:

```js
  
     let json = {
    "countries": [{
            "country": "Albania",
            "code": "AL",
            "flag": "https://media.api-football.com/flags/al.svg"
        },
        {
            "country": "Algeria",
            "code": "DZ",
            "flag": "https://media.api-football.com/flags/dz.svg"
        },
        {
            "country": "Honduras",
            "code": "HN",
            "flag": "https://media.api-football.com/flags/hn.svg"
        }
    ]
};
let html = ``;

json.countries.forEach((e, i) => {
    html += `<tr><td id="${e.code}" onclick="infoCountry(this)"><img src="${e.flag}"></img><p>${e.country}</p></td><tr>`;
});
document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = html;
const infoCountry = (target) => {
    let country = target.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerText;

    alert('this country is ' + country)
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <table id="country">
  
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Cannot read property 'x' of undefined means that you're trying to access a property of a null object. Try to log jsonData.api.countries[i+1]. My guess is that once you reach the last index of your for loop, you try to access the i+1 object that doesn't exist. You may want to continue your for loop until `jsonData.api.countries.length-1` instead.

Comment: But if i want the next cell to contain data from the secound index of array, how do i do that then? thats why i in first place used jsonData.api.countries[i+1], any suggestion?